# Trying to move cells based off of data

Tags: excel, vba

The code works but when moving the cells it pastes them 2 below the bottom cell. Basically i just need them to paste without any empty cells

```
            Dim rw11 As Long
            Dim lastrow11 As Long
            lastrow11 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
            For rw11 = 1000 To 1 Step -1


                With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
                    If .Cells(rw11, 2).Value Like "*Player Number*" Then
                        ' Cut the value and then blank the source and shift up
                        .Cells(rw11, 2).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow11, 3)
                        .Cells(rw11, 2).Delete (xlUp)
                    End If
                End With
            lastrow11 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row + 1
            Next
```

Comment: I'd assume it's the `lastRow11` getting set two rows too far? Assuming your column B has the most data, perhaps try `lastRow11 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: So im using that code but its still grabbing the row length from the longest row and not the specified row

Comment: Perhaps change 2 to 3 in Bruce's code.

Comment: @SJR ya thats what i used. I have tried both 2 and 3 and have no idea why its not working

Comment: Have you changed both `lastrow11` lines (you only need it once) and add a "+1" to the end of Bruce's line.

Comment: @SJR I just edited my code... didnt mean to add the top one. What do you suggest i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? You don't strictly need the last row variable at all. The only reason I can think of for your code not working is that it was defined twice and UsedRange is not reliable as it can "remember" previous cell contents.

```
Sub x()

Dim rw11 As Long

For rw11 = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Cells(rw11, 2).Value Like "*Player Number*" Then
            .Cells(rw11, 2).Cut Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)(2)
            .Cells(rw11, 2).Delete (xlUp)
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks again for the help :))